# Why JQuery Autocomplete displays only one item?

Tags: jquery, html, django

Am using JQuery Autocomplete on my templete, but as i get the results the Autocomplete only displays one item despite that the results that are fetched have more that one item. It only shows the first item on the list!

Example:

if i have a result list with **('python', 'pythonism', 'pythodus')**

and on the autocomplete i type **'pyt'** it only displays **'python'** on the drop down!

My autocomplete code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#tags1").autocomplete("/taglookup/", {
        width: 320,
        max: 4,
        highlight: false,
        multiple: true,
        multipleSeparator:",",
        scroll: true,
        scrollHeight: 300,
        delay: 10
         });

      });
```

my AJAX django view that gets called:

```
def tag_lookup(request):
    # Default return list
    results = []
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.GET.has_key(u'q'):
            value = request.GET[u'q']
            # Ignore queries shorter than length 3
            if len(value) > 2:
                TI = Tag.objects.filter(name__contains=value)
                print TI
                results = [ x.name for x in TI]
    print results #shows me more than one item is returned
    return HttpResponse('|'.join(results), mimetype='text/plain')
```

Comment: Have you checked the output of your django? please post it also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys, just discovered that the JQuery Autocomplete plugin am using requires a new line character as a separator between items, so i have replaced my Ajax Django view to read like this;

```
 return HttpResponse('\n'.join(results), mimetype='text/plain')
```

its working perfect!

Thanks.

Comment: Answered your own question. +1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `HttpResponse` is doing `Something|Something|...` where the jQuery is wanting `Something,Something,...`. Try changing `multipleSeparator` to `'|'`. Also, since I don't know the use of the print before the `HttpResponse`.

Comment: If i replace  "|" with "," nothing get displayed even the one item.